# Android app built in eclipse wont run on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I've built an app that runs fine on the emulators, and says that it installs ok on the phone. However, on trying to run it an error pops up saying 'Application is not installed on your phone'. So I tried running the app through eclipse on the phone and I got this error in the console:

```
[2012-05-01 12:00:02 - MAD Assignment] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mad.assignment/.MainMenu }
[2012-05-01 12:00:02 - MAD Assignment] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mad.assignment/.MainMenu } from null (pid=8204, uid=2000) requires null
```

From looking for the solution elsewhere it sounds as though it could be a problem in the manifest file, so here is mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mad.assignment"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
     >
    <activity
        android:name="MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Diary"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Info"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapMenu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSMenu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSFeedView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainMenu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSDetailed"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiarySchedule"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryAddEntry"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryEditEntry"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryDetailed"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSDetailed"></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".MapMain"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSFeedView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapWhatsNearPreferences"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RoutePath"></activity>
</application>
```

Any ideas what this security exception is pointing to? Thanks!

Comment: the meaningful part of your error message is cut off, you need to post the full width

Comment: may be you are trying to declare the same activity twice.delete <activity android:name=".MainMenu"></activity>

and try again.

Comment: That's the full error in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java.lang.SecurityException you are seeing is because you may enter two entries pointing to same activity. Remove the second one and you should be good to go.

You may be declared the activity 2 times in the manifest with different properties, like :

```
 <activity android:name=".MainMenu"> </activity>
```

and

```
 <activity android:name=".MainMenu" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
     <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

You should remove the unwanted one from the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:debuggable="true"` under application.

Answer (score 0):

You have an activity named

```
<activity android:name=".MainMenu"></activity>
```

Which is the Intent'ed activity from the launcher. But the activity to which you gave permission is  "Mainmenu".  Remove it. Add the permission and etc  to the ".Mainmenu" which is blank now.

ie,

The  'activity' group should be

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Diary"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Info"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapMenu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSMenu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiarySchedule"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryAddEntry"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryEditEntry"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DiaryDetailed"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSDetailed"></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".MapMain"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RSSFeedView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapWhatsNearPreferences"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RoutePath"></activity>
```

And remove the duplicates as well. Why did you add so many duplicate 'activities' ?